# Magic ui:repeat var

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, scope, uirepeat

I have stumbled upon an, at least for me, unexpected behaviour. When using an ui:repeat, it seems I can access the var from outside.

Code - Page:

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{xTest.init()}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:form id="xTestForm">
   <h:panelGroup layout="block">
      Track: #{trk.name}
   </h:panelGroup>

   <table>
      <ui:repeat
         value="#{xTest.trackList}"
         var="trk">
         <tr>
            <td>#{trk.name}</td>
            <td>
               <p:commandLink
                  actionListener="#{xTest.setTrack(track)}"
                  value="test"
                  update=":xTestForm" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </ui:repeat>
   </table>
</h:form>
```

Code - Bean

```
package beans;

import dao.DAOFactory;
import dao.track.TrackDAO;
import dto.Track;
import exceptions.DAOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import util.MessageUtil;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class xTest implements Serializable {

    private DAOFactory daoFactory = Config.getInstance().getDAOFactory();
    private TrackDAO trackDAO;
    private Track track = new Track();
    private MessageUtil msg = new MessageUtil();
    private List<Track> trackList = new ArrayList();

    public xTest() {
        trackDAO = daoFactory.getTrackDAO(true);
    }

    public void init() {
        if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
            try {
                trackList = trackDAO.listByAlbumid(241);
            } catch (SQLException | DAOException ex) {
                msg.setErrorMessage(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Track> getTrackList() {
        return trackList;
    }

    public void setTrack(Track track) {
        this.track = track;
    }
}
```

If I click a link in the list of tracks, the track name will be displayed in the panelGroup. How is this possible?

Comment: Ask [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1137911/1530938). The age old compile time V render-time discrepancy :)

Comment: Being somewhat limited in my knowledge about the more fine grained workings of JSF, I still don't understand how the ui:repeat var is suddenly valid outside the Component. My previous understanding was that it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in Mojarra. Its `UIRepeat` component forgets to remove the iteration variable from the request scope by end of iteration during restore view phase. It doesn't work that way in for example MyFaces.

You shouldn't rely your business code on it. Note that `<h:dataTable>` doesn't have this problem, it properly removes the iteration variable from the request scope by end of iteration by [`((UIData) component).setRowIndex(-1)` in `encodeEnd()` method](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/2.3.14/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/TableRenderer.java#L167).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification BalusC. Now I will move on to a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

8 years later someone reported this to PrimeFaces so I opened a Mojarra issue and a PR to fix the issue.

Mojarra Issue: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4830

Mojarra PR: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/pull/4831